# Solving a TSP-related task

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman, approximation

I have a problem similar to the basic TSP but not quite the same.

I have a starting position for a player character, and he has to pick up n objects in the shortest time possible. He doesn't need to return to the original position and the order in which he picks up the objects does not matter.

In other words, the problem is to find the minimum-weight (distance) Hamiltonian path with a given (fixed) start vertex.

What I have currently, is an algorithm like this:

```
best_total_weight_so_far = Inf

foreach possible end vertex:
    add a vertex with 0-weight edges to the start and end vertices
    current_solution = solve TSP for this graph
    remove the 0 vertex

    total_weight = Weight (current_solution)
    if total_weight < best_total_weight_so_far
        best_solution = current_solution
        best_total_weight_so_far = total_weight
```

However this algorithm seems to be somewhat time-consuming, since it has to solve the TSP n-1 times. Is there a better approach to solving the original problem?

Comment: So out of curiosity, what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a rather minor variation of TSP and clearly NP-hard. Any heuristic algorithm (and you really shouldn't try to do anything better than heuristic for a game IMHO) for TSP should be easily modifiable for your situation. Even the nearest neighbor probably wouldn't be bad -- in fact for your situation it would probably be better that when used in TSP since in Nearest Neighbor the return edge is often the worst. Perhaps you can use NN + [2-Opt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-opt) to eliminate edge crossings.

On edit: Your problem can easily be reduced to the TSP problem for *directed* graphs. Double all of the existing edges so that each is replaced by a pair of arrows. The costs for all arrows is simply the existing cost for the corresponding edges *except* for the arrows that go into the start node. Make those edges cost 0 (no cost in returning at the end of the day). If you have code that solves the TSP for directed graphs you could thus use it in your case as well.

Comment: The nearest neighbour approach is what I'm using in my current implementation. I was just being curious if there was a decent exact algorithm possible for this case, since n is going to be relatively low (definitely <20 and likely <10) - so yes, even a naive "check all possibilities" algorithm would probably work here, though there probably are better alternatives.

Anyway, the 2-Opt addition seems like a good idea, I will probably go with that.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of it getting slow (20 points should be fine), you can use the good old exact TSP algorithms in the way John describes. 20 points is really easy for TSP - instances with thousands of points are routinely solved and instances with tens of thousands of points have been solved.

For example, use linear programming and branch & bound.

Make an LP problem with one variable per edge (there are more edges now because it's directed), the variables will be between 0 and 1 where 0 means "don't take this edge in the solution", 1 means "take it" and fractional values sort of mean "take it .. a bit" (whatever that means).

The costs are obviously the distances, except for returning to the start. See John's answer.

Then you need constraints, namely that for each node the sum of its incoming edges is 1, and the sum of its outgoing edges is one. Also the sum of a pair of edges that was previously one edge must be smaller or equal to one. The solution now will consist of disconnected triangles, which is the smallest way to connect the nodes such that they all have both an incoming edge and an outgoing edge, and those edges are not both "the same edge". So the sub-tours must be eliminated. The simplest way to do that (probably strong enough for 20 points) is to decompose the solution into connected components, and then for each connected component say that the sum of incoming edges to it must be at least 1 (it can be more than 1), same thing with the outgoing edges. Solve the LP problem again and repeat this until there is only one component. There are more cuts you can do, such as the obvious Gomory cuts, but also fancy special TSP cuts (comb cuts, blossom cuts, crown cuts.. there are whole books about this), but you won't need any of this for 20 points.

What this gives you is, sometimes, directly the solution. Usually to begin with it will contain fractional edges. In that case it still gives you a good underestimation of how long the tour will be, and you can use that in the framework of branch & bound to determine the actual best tour. The idea there is to pick an edge that was fractional in the result, and pick it either 0 or 1 (this often turns edges that were previously 0/1 fractional, so you have to keep all "chosen edges" fixed in the whole sub-tree in order to guarantee termination). Now you have two sub-problems, solve each recursively. Whenever the estimation from the LP solution becomes longer than the best path you have found so far, you can prune the sub-tree (since it's an underestimation, all integral solutions in this part of the tree can only be *even worse*). You can initialize the "best so far solution" with a heuristic solution but for 20 points it doesn't really matter, the techniques I described here are already enough to solve 100-point problems.